# Issues in removing password login Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2

Tags: ssh, raspbian-stretch, password

> NOTE : I have referenced lot of websites and referenced stack overflow
>   answers but its not working for me

I have set up `ssh` login for my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2 and its working like a breeze.

Now I want to make it more secure by removing password login for my **pi** user. So, I did the following changes in the file **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

From

```
#PasswordAuthentication Yes
```

To

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Save and exit the file

Then

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Even tried rebooting the Pi

But when I connect with other devices its prompting for Password, which it must not happen.

It must not allow any prompts for password and must show error. How can I achieve this?

References:

https://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2012/05/30/logging-into-a-rasberry-pi-using-publicprivate-keys/

https://dvpizone.wordpress.com/2014/03/02/how-to-connect-to-your-raspberry-pi-using-ssh-key-pairs/

Comment: If you refere to other websites, please add the url's!

Comment: Try to connect using `ssh -vv ...` and edit in the output above.

Comment: Maybe ssh is asking for the password to unlock your private key and everything is working well?

Comment: duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373290/ssh-disable-password-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fully disable password-based authentication, set BOTH `PasswordAuthentication` and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` to `no`.

Comment: Thanks @Matsk it worked for me. Was actually ssh ing from juice ssh from android mobile. So it was showing password. Elsewhere its working awesome.

Answer (score 1):

If you look [here](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/openssh-server/sshd_config.5.en.html), you can set how users authenticate themselves (the order of the authentications used). Just set `AuthenticationMethods` to `publickey`, it should not be going to a password. Use this in combination with the other answer (disable password authentication).